# how to check the checkbox when the layout is clicked?

Tags: java, android, android-relativelayout, android-checkbox

I have a relative layout. In that relative layout i have a textview at left end and check box at right end. Now
what i want is, when i clicked the entire layout( above relative layout) the check box need to check. any please 
help me.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/layoutavailable"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/layouttaxexempt"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
    >


    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/txt_avl"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:hint="IsAlwaysAvailable"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textColorHint="@color/white"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="13dp"
        />

    <CheckBox 
       android:id="@+id/c_avl"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "above relative layout"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the listener to the layout

```
 CheckBox cBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.c_avl);
 findViewById(R.id.layoutavailable).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {             
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
          cBox.setChecked(!cBox.isChecked());                
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 4):

Code:

```
public void onClick(View v) {

    if (checkbox.isChecked()){
        checkbox.setChecked(false);
    }
    else {
        checkbox.setChecked(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use CheckedTextView instead of normal TextView.

And make CheckedTextView width and height to match_parent"

Answer (score 0):

Just try this:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

RelativeLayout layout;
CheckBox cb;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    cb=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
    layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.layoutavailable);
    layout.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {
            cb.setChecked(true);
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do by following way

```
    yourRelativeLayout.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            youCheckbox.setChecked(!(test.isChecked()));

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

First make your Relative Layout clickable by writing the given code in your Relative Layout Tag body, and also assign the id to your layout.:-

```
android:clickable="true"
android:id="@+id/rl"
```

Then in your Activity Java file, write the code in your on create instance:-

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.test2);
        Relative Layout rl = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.rl);
        final CheckBox c_avl = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
        rl.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                c_avl.setChecked(true);
            }
        });
    }
```

This will certainly solve your problem, indeed.

Answer (score 0):

You can also achieve this by using the toggle() method of the CheckBox class. Please note that when using the toggle method, there won't be any animation. The way that I fixed that issue was by overriding the toggle method, and defining my own toggle.

```
private RelativeLayout layoutAvailable = findViewById(R.id.layoutavailable);
private CheckBox cAvl = findViewById(R.id.c_avl);
layoutavailable.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(View view){
        cAvl.toggle();
    }
})
```

Answer (score -1):

Just pass the state of the parent `RelativeLayout` to it's child `CheckBox`

set `RelativeLayout` clickable, and add an attribute `android:duplicateParentState` to `CheckBox`

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/layoutavailable"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/layouttaxexempt"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    >


    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/txt_avl"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:hint="IsAlwaysAvailable"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textColorHint="@color/white"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="13dp"
        />

    <CheckBox 
       android:id="@+id/c_avl"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:duplicateParentState='true'
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: its not working though it showing check box is also click when layout is clicked but its not getting checked or unchecked